# Read to Cache in Write-Allocate policy

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-cache

[write-allocate diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oceUd.png)

What is the read-to-cache for in this case ?

To my understanding, the Store is paused while an address in the cache memory is allocated after the Write-Back occurs (to clear a line if the dirty bit is set). And then the Store can occur. But what is the read-to-cache doing in this case?

Comment: The read to cache is filling the cache line. Typically validity is tracked at line granularity, so either the entire line needs to have valid data or the line cannot be marked as valid. (Store buffers typically track validity at finer granularity.) This is called read for ownership.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton 

But if the read-to-cache is filling the cache line, then what does the Store do ?

Comment: The store inserts a new value for a portion of the cache line. The cache line read could alternatively be loaded into the store buffer, avoiding the extra access of the cache itself; this is more of an implementation detail. (Read-for-ownership is also making the assumption that loads have spatial locality with stores, i.e., if one stores to a location, one is likely to load soon from a nearby location, particularly within the same cache line.)